# festival text to speech unable to add CMU US BDL ARCTIC 0.95 voice

Tags: debian-jessie

I am trying to install the *CMU US BDL ARCTIC 0.95* voice for use with festival.

I am on debian 8 and have festival version 2.1

Here is what I have done:

```
cd /usr/share/festival/voices/english/
sudo wget -c http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cmu_arctic/packed/cmu_us_bdl_arctic-0.95-release.tar.bz2
sudo tar jxf cmu_us_bdl_arctic-0.95-release.tar.bz2 
sudo ln -s cmu_us_bdl_arctic cmu_us_bdl_arctic_clunits
sudo echo "(set! voice_default 'voice_cmu_us_bdl_arctic_clunits)" >> /etc/festival.scm
```

However when I run it, I get the error:

```
$ echo "This is a test." | festival --tts
SIOD ERROR: unbound variable : voice_cmu_us_bdl_arctic_clunits
Error evaluating default voice: voice_cmu_us_bdl_arctic_clunits
continuing
-=-=-=-=-=- EST Error -=-=-=-=-=-
{FND} Feature Token_Method not defined

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
```

Comment: Same thing happening to me also. I'm installing the voice with [this line](https://github.com/DragonComputer/Dragonfire/blob/master/install.sh#L2) and the same error pops up. In the past like a year ago or so, it was working perfectly fine. Probably someone messed up [the festival package](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/festival) in Debian repository. I will try to report it, please let me know if you fixed the error.